# Does anyone know who the manufacturer of this window is?

Tags: windows, replacement, glass

Can you tell me who the manufacturer of this window is based on barcodes:

Also is it cheaper to replace the whole window or just replace the broken glass?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would think that just replacing the glass will be cheaper than a whole window, but funny things can happen if the window maker gets bulk pricing.  Will need to get the local prices for windows and glass repair to compare.

Comment: Usually you can buy a pane of window glass for $15 or less (depending on dimensions, thickness, etc.)

Comment: Google glazier to find someone who can do it. Barcodes like these are internally generated. I did check, it is not a valid UpC barcode

Comment: Probably narrow the manufacturer down to America...

Comment: @gnicko that seems awfully cheap for an IGU...

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly going to be cheaper to replace the glass.  I assume this is a modern window with double pane glass.  Typically one side of the window frame will have removable pieces that allow a new pane to be put into the frame.

Normally you pay for two trips for a window company - one to measure and one to install.  Depending on labor rates in your area and the somewhat the size of the window, I'd expect less than $1000.  You could order the glass yourself and install, a double pane piece of glass is likely to be less than $500.  Typically glass companies make the glazing units and window companies make frames that will take glass.  You'll probably have to order the glass from a glazing company that does installs as glass companies typically sell to window manufactures or glazers.

If you need to replace the window then you open up a can of works in terms of the siding details and interior trim details.  You could go with the retrofit window in a window frame but that almost always looks terrible and would still cost more than the glass.  Also it can be hard to match the other existing windows if you care anything about how the job looks.